# JBoss WAR Deployment problem (caching problems?)

Tags: java, jboss, war

I'm trying to deploy my war file on JBoss 4.2.3. This application was working fine and still is working fine (sans the bugfix that I've put into my code). I have made a new war file with a bug fix in it (which involves passing some extra http request params while requesting another app's servlet). However, when I tried to deploy this seemingly innocuous war file, I see the console logs from Jboss that say the new war file has been deployed etc. However, I don't see my changes reflecting in the browser (i.e, the extra params are not being sent in the request). I've verified that the war file that has gone into `/server/default/deploy` is exactly the same (cksum's are the same). I tried these few usual tricks to no avail: deleted the old war file from server before deploying the new one, restarted the server to free any cached stuff. Even put a return in my servlet at entry point. But still no difference! The servlet works just like before without the fix. Any suggestions?
I request you to kindly help me. I kinda screwed if this doesn't work.

Comment: The most logical explanation is that the new WAR file doesn't contain the fix.

Comment: Does the JBoss log confirm the re-deployment?
There should be a sign of first undeployment of the previous WAS, and then a deployment of the new one.

Comment: I have this exact problem on JBoss 5.1.0.  I delete my old WAR, then tell it to deploy, and it's obviously not loading the new classes -- I can actually examine the classes in the WAR file, see the changes, but I'm still getting impossible results, like stack dumps that reference lines of code that are long removed.  Still searching for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts

- maybe your browser is 'offline' or using the cache, try clearing the cache / refresh
- delete the contents under the server/default/tmp and server/default/work folders also

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some logging statements to your application, and see if they're output when you redeploy the war...

If it is definitely being redeployed then perhaps, as skaffman says, the fix didn't work.